# calling member functions from within another member function of the same class in C++, objective C

Tags: c++, function, static-methods, member, access-specifier

Consider the following:

```
class A{

    //data members

    void foo()
    {
        bar();//is this possible? or should you say this->bar() note that bar is not static
    }
    void bar()
    {

    }
}//end of class A
```

How do you call member functions from within another? And how does static functions affect the use of 'this'.
Should functions be called on an object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nawaz is correct:  'this' is implicit.  The one exception is if foo were a static function, because in static functions there is no 'this'.  In that case, you can't use bar() unless bar() is also a static function, and you can't use this->bar() at all.

Comment: There's also weird cases where you're calling a non-static member of a base that's not automatically brought into the current scope, and you've not done it explicitly with a `using` statement, but the poster's clearly got simpler things to worry about.

Comment: @Tony: Could you please elaborate on those weird cases?

Comment: @Namratha: I've never paid a lot of attention - it's more one of those things you just learn to recognise and fix when the compiler complains rather than remembering the exact issue, but from vague memory: if the derived class has a function named x() then templated x()s in the base class won't be brought into scope unless explicitly requested with `using`.

Answer (score 4):

```
bar();//is this possible? or should you say this->bar()
```

`this` is implicit. So both of them are equivalent. You can use any of them. But then I think, if just `bar()` is enough, then why use `this->bar()`?

Use `this` only when there is some ambiguity, otherwise use the simpler one!

Comment: Is the function call bar() allowed if it is not a static function? Is it not necessary to call bar on an object?

Comment: @Namratha: Are you not repeating yourself? Did I not say both of them are equivalent? Why don't you write some code and see yourself if `bar()` is getting called or not?

Comment: No because your answer is not clear. You haven't answered my question regarding the static keyword and when functions must be called on an object.